# Пытаюсь сделать калькулятор не могу сделать чтоб при делении на 0 выводился текст ERROR,выводится Infinity

Tags: java, android

```
  public String operator(String a, String b, String op) {
    try {
        double a1 = Double.valueOf(a);
        double b1 = Double.valueOf(b);
        double res = 0;
        switch (op) {
            case "+":
                res = a1 + b1;

            case "-":
                res = a1 - b1;
                break;
            case "*":
                res = a1 * b1;
                break;
            case "/":
                res = a1 / b1;
        }
        if ((res == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) || (res == 
    Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {
    System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return String.valueOf(res);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        return "E R R O R:";
    }

}
   public void clickEquals(View v) {

    String[] operation = display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperation));
    String result =operator(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperation);
    Double ress= Double.valueOf(result);
    if ((ress * 10) % 10 == 0) {
        String rezultat = String.valueOf(result);
        txtv.setText(display + "=" + rezultat.substring(0, 
     rezultat.length() 
    - 2));
    } else {
        txtv.setText(display + "=" + String.valueOf(result));

    }
```

Comment: а куда вы хотите выводить это сообщение? `TextView` или `Toast`? или просто в логи?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь бесконечности не сраниваются, тут нужно проверять методом `Double.isNaN()`

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko В TextView

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko  В методе "clickEquals"  я использую метод "operator".Я добавила метод можете посмотреть

Comment: да уже вижу, сейчас попробую помочь с учетом вашей ситуации.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Огромное спасибо

Comment: а вы не пробовали вашу переменную к `string` приводить так - result.toString? просто ваше сообщений `infinite` выводит потому-что неправильно переводите `double` в `string`.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Что только я не делала)Если вы об этом:else {
            txtv.setText(display + "=" + result.toString()); ещё раз попробовала ,не то.

Comment: так давайте сначала, вам не нужно выводить 0, вам нужно просто выводить текст `error` ? если это так то тогда вам не нужно заморачиваться с переводом результата в строку, просто выводите сразу ерор меседж и все, для начала я бы проверил, правильно ли программа реагирует на 0, вставьте какой-то `toast`  например, и дальше посмотрите если сообщение всплывает, то дальше просто сделайте в `textView` нужное вам сообщение и все. Но это при условии что вам не нужен именно результат в поле, когда у вас 0.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте такую проверку `Double.valueOf(res).isInfinite();`

Comment: в случае 0.0/0.0 это не будет работать, там нужно еще добавить проверку с  `Double.isNan`

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в арифметических операциях у вас операторы `double`, а в Java представления с плавающей запятой основаны на стандарте [IEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), в котором описано, что при делении на 0 по-умолчанию возвращается `±infinity`, то есть в этом случае ошибка `ArithmeticException` не возникает. Далее. если посмотреть приведенный вами код, то можно заметить, что вроде как и проверяете результат на `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` и `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, но при этом ничего не делаете в результате проверки.

```
if ((res == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) || (res == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {
    // Что делать?
    // в вашем случае, возможно хотели здесь вернуть return "E R R O R:";
    // или throw new ArithmeticException();
}
```

Comment: Я там  sout(); текст выводила, не реагирует.Просто код тысячу раз меняла ,забыла исправить

Comment: @Liona, во-первых, если смотреть логи, то `System.out.println("Error");` таки отрабатывает - пишет в лог "Error", но при этом, после вывода в лог, вы все равно из функции возвращаете `±infinity`, так как нет выхода из функции и sout() еще не означает, что из функции возвратится "Error". Во-вторых, даже если вы возвратите из функции "Error", то у вас далее код споткнется на строке `Double ress= Double.valueOf(result);` с ошибкой `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Сделала,в методе тоже сделала try catch,всё получилось вроде